# undefined macro 'assert_ne!' on TravisCI

Tags: rust, travis-ci

I'm able to test and build [my project](https://github.com/afshinm/juggernaut) on my local machine but when I want TravisCI to build the project, it says:

```
error: macro undefined: 'assert_ne!'
```

I have [added two different versions of Rust but both returns the same error](https://travis-ci.org/afshinm/juggernaut/jobs/229394671).

Do I need to import this macro before using it? If so, why does it work with no problems on my machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's undefined because it doesn't exist in those versions.

If you check the [documentation for `assert_ne!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/macro.assert_ne.html), you will note that it was introduced in version 1.12.  You are testing against Rust 1.0 and 1.1.

Comment: I'm so sorry for asking such a basic question.

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani Why did you use 1.0 and 1.1? Was this copy and pasted from somewhere? Maybe that somewhere could do with some better defaults. 1.0 and 1.1 are quite ancient. Maybe it might be good to change that somewhere to recommend stable or something.